# How to write unit test for Angular Material Chips?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the chips with input [here](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview#chip-input)

How to write unit test for add and remove functions?

In case of remove we can mock using a array and string, but how to test the remove function.

HTML

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list">
  <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Fruit selection">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let fruit of fruits" [selectable]="selectable"
             [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(fruit)">
      {{fruit.name}}
      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
    </mat-chip>
    <input placeholder="New fruit..."
           [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
  </mat-chip-list>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS

```
  add(event: MatChipInputEvent): void {
    const input = event.input;
    const value = event.value;

    // Add our fruit
    if ((value || '').trim()) {
      this.fruits.push({name: value.trim()});
    }

    // Reset the input value
    if (input) {
      input.value = '';
    }
  }

  remove(fruit: Fruit): void {
    const index = this.fruits.indexOf(fruit);

    if (index >= 0) {
      this.fruits.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
```

[Link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/endvyklbknj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-input-example.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not bother testing Material Chips, because the Material components have their own tests. No need to test the framework.

Instead, I think you should test the methods that manipulate the data that is bound to the chips (add, remove, etc.)

This will make testing much simpler, because your tests will not need to be Angular-aware.

And if your Component can't be instantiated and have those methods be called without involving the framework, I would extract those methods into another class, perhaps a service, that can.

Comment: That's exactly what my question is, how to test the method add as it is triggered by event of material, Can you share the test code?

Comment: My point is that you don't need to get Material involved. Just write tests that directly call those methods, and assert that after the call, the data is what you expect it to be.

Comment: But the add method needs MatChipInputEvent type of parameter, can you please show me how to pass the parameter, in order to test the function. https://stackblitz.com/angular/endvyklbknj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchips-input-example.ts

Comment: MatChipInputEvent is an interface, so you can just create an object that has the required properties. Try this:

`    this.add({
       input: null, 
       value: 'test'
     } as unknown as MatChipInputEvent);
`

The cast to 'unknown' is because null isn't convertible to an HTMLInputElement - this gets that past the compiler.

Comment: How it can be the accepted answer. The quesion is how to write tests. The answer can't be "don't"...

Comment: The point is to test your code, not the framework. The framework has its own tests.

Comment: I'm confusing that although the code is being tested, but we can't know that the program is work properly or not, because the way we test here is to call the method directly rather than interact to the real UI. The Angular Material CDK does provide some library for testing purpose, so I think this is not the right solution.

Answer (score 2):

I was also stuck with this problem since I'm still learning angular.
I read several other similar stackoverflow questions that had bits and pieces of what I needed, but were not the solution to this question.

The answer to your question is in two parts.

1. To Add you need to get the nativeElement for your input field. This way you can use it in the add event as the MatChipInputEvent.

You can add an id to you input, so you can pull in the nativeElement:

```xml
<input placeholder="New fruit..."
    [id]="input-fruit-id"
    [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
    [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
    [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
    (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
>
```

Next in the test you will need add code the following to get the nativeElement and use it in your function.

```js
const inputElement: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
    By.css('#input-fruit-id')
).nativeElement;
component.add({
    input: inputElement,
    value: <put a test value here, for example: 'orange'>,
} as MatChipInputEvent);
fixture.detectChanges();
```

Next check your list of fruits to see that the value was added.

2. This part is what GreyBeardedGeek mentioned. You only need to test your function and not the MatChip. Here is how I would test the remove:

```js
const fruitList = [ 'orange', 'apple', 'peach' ];
component.fruits = fruitList;
       
component.remove('orange');
fixture.DetectChanges();
```

Now check that 'orange' has been removed from the list.